# Set height css property using bootstrap without !important

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Wondering how could I set a `height` property from a class selector when using Bootstrap classes without `!important`?

Comment: Did you try including your stylsheet after the bootstrap one?

Comment: Read about specificity here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: You can always use tricks to increase the specificity like adding `body` in front. `body .whateverYourClassIs {styles}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If more than one rule is applied to the same element and there is a
clash it is resolved using precedence rules. Specificity is an
important aspect of precedence rules in CSS. Rule selection mainly
checks which rule refers to the HTML element in the most specific way.
The rule with the most specific reference to the element will be
applied to the element."

**Only way to override specificity is by using a keyword `!important`. To briefly list the different cases in precedence order:**

1. Style declared in ""style attribute"" with !important keyword.
2. Style declared in ""stylesheet"" with !important attribute.
3. Normal style declared in style attribute (without !important attribute).
4. Normal Style in style sheet.

Declaring the style right there in the HTML element is the most specific way to refer to it.

---

### A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:

1. Count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
2. Count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
3. Count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
   ignore the universal selector
4. Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other, but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.
5. Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

---

So just doing

```
body .myClass
```

has more precedence than

```
.myClass
```